# List indices must be integers or slices, not str while working with a json file

Tags: python, api

I am trying to parse data from an API which I converted to json but I keep getting this error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". I am a newbie with python so I don't understand how to fix it.

```
from urllib import response
import requests
import json 

PinCode = input("Enter Your 6 digit Pincode for the Area: ")
Date = input("Enter the Date in DD-MM-YYYY format: ")

BaseUrl = "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByPin?"
Url = BaseUrl +"pincode="+PinCode+"&date="+Date 
response = requests.get(Url)
data = response.json()
sessions = data['sessions']
NameVac = sessions['name']
AddressVac = sessions['address']
FromVac = sessions['from']
ToVac = sessions['to']
AvailableCap = sessions['available_capacity']
AvailableCapDose1 = sessions['available_capacity_dose1']
AvailableCapDose2 = sessions['available_capacity_dose2']
MinimumAge = sessions['min_age_limit']
VaccineType = sessions['vaccine']
print(f"Details for {PinCode}")
```

The JSON Sample:

```
{
  "sessions": [
    {
      "center_id": 709195,
      "name": "SKV School Mahipalpur Site 1",
      "address": "Amar Shaheed Major Sherawat SKV Kishangarh - Mehrauli Rd L Block Mahipalpur Village Mahipalpur New Delhi Delhi 110037",
      "state_name": "Delhi",
      "district_name": "New Delhi",
      "block_name": "Not Applicable",
      "pincode": 110037,
      "from": "09:00:00",
      "to": "15:00:00",
      "lat": 28,
      "long": 77,
      "fee_type": "Free",
      "session_id": "6c10bbf1-3e70-464b-9932-8000ad3f7ef3",
      "date": "30-01-2022",
      "available_capacity": 120,
      "available_capacity_dose1": 50,
      "available_capacity_dose2": 50,
      "fee": "0",
      "min_age_limit": 18,
      "max_age_limit": 44,
      "allow_all_age": false,
      "vaccine": "COVISHIELD",
      "slots": [
        "09:00AM-10:00AM",
        "10:00AM-11:00AM",
        "11:00AM-12:00PM",
        "12:00PM-03:00PM"
      ]
    }
```

The Output traceback:

```
File "c:\pythonprojects\covid-vac.py", line 13, in <module>
    NameVac = sessions['name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Show us a JSON sample and the full error traceback!

Comment: Maybe change `sessions = data['sessions']` to `sessions = data['sessions'][0]` since it is  list containing a dictionary rather than a dictionary in its own right.

Comment: yeah it works, anyway I can iterate it so it lists out all the sessions rather than one ?

Comment: @KlausD Please check now!

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you! it only works for one instance, anyway I can iterate it ?